# Scalable and Fast restart able cache

Tags: caching

I am after a scalable & fast restartable caching solution which has a provision to boot up quickly (E.g. storing the cache on disk during application shut down (or while running) and restoring it back while application comes up) and can maintain a few GB size of cache. (Our cache is not a distributed cache)

Enterprise ehcache/BigMemory Go (http://ww1.terracotta.org/documentation/3.7.4/bigmemorygo/configuration/fast-restart) supports this feature but they are licensed.

Any other suggestions are also welcome. I dont want to use Gemfire or Geode as they need different infra to maintain.

Comment: [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb) would be a good fit

Comment: Could see this is also failing in same line..